# Twitter Bootstrap and bigger than a standard icon in the button

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, height, padding

Everything is perfect when I use:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> text
</button>
```

I want my own icon. That's why I use:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-school icon-white"></i> text
</button>
```

My icon is displayed in the button, but my icon is a bit higher (20px x 16px). So, it is displayed for 75%. How to fix it? 
Changing height or padding doesn't help.

Thank you.

Comment: For a simple life maybe resize your icon to be the same size as the default bootstrap icons?

Comment: Can't do that, that's not under my power:)

Comment: Just for everybody: I didn't find a good solution. Changing height doesn't help too much either as the text becomes not vertically centered. Working with padding, background-position doesn't make it perfect. The size of the image was reduced to keep it Twitter Boostrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `icon-perso` class

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="icon-school icon-perso"></i> text
</button>
```

Add the following css to override the default behaviour with:

- the url of your picture
- the width and height of the picture
- change the line-height to the picture height
- margins if required

.

```
.icon-perso {
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-perso.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

If you picture contain several icons like glyphicons-halflings.png you may have to change the background-position

```
.icon-school {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

You can have a look at `bootstrap.css` around from line 2143 if you are curious.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to extend the **bootstrap** icon sprite and add one more row on the css with the exact position of your new icon.

Search for one of the bootstrap icons and add your below.

I do always in this way also if my icon is bigger, just change the width / height of your only.